# Как исключить директиву из DOM angular

Tags: angularjs

Как исключить динамично директиву из шаблона?
вот есть одна директива

```
app.directive('parent', function() {
      return {
        link:function(scope, element) {
            scope.showChild = false;
        },
        template:'<div> <h3> Parent directive </h3>  <child-dir ng-show="showChild"></child-dir> </div>'

      };

});

app.directive('childDir', function() {
    return {
         template:'<div> Child directive! </div>',
         link:function() { 
            /*  some code */

         }
    };

});
```

Когда я просто скрываю ее, то все равно логика которая внутри link в директиве childDir всеравно отрабатывает а мне нужно вобще исключить директиву из DOM что-бы она даже не запускалась

Answer (score 3, accepted):

директива [ng-if](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) - в отличие от `ng-show`/`ng-hide` - удаляет или добавляет элемент, а не просто меняет стиль.